# Can't access login page of wired connection - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: internet, wired

My university has a login page to which I am redirected to if at all the internet access is not detected. However, after updating my Ubuntu I am not able to do that if I am connected to the network via a wired connection. However, I can access the login page if I am connected to the network via a Wi-Fi. I have been trying to fix this problem for a lot of time but to no avail. Any suggestions to fix this problem are welcome.

Comment: I don't know what the reason is, but I can access the login page when I connect my computer to some other ethernet port. I don't know how this is even possible.